# Set the CALayer's borderWidth property to affect only the left and right borders?

Tags: ios, uitableview, selection, quartz-core

I'm trying to make a custom color for a UITableViewCell selection. I don't want the entire cell to highlight when I press it, in other words the frame of the selection background should be (10,cell.frame.origin.y,300,cell.frame.size.height). I tried to give the backgroundColorView.layer.borderWidth property a value of 10, but that affects the entire view, and not only the left-right borders. This is the code I'm now stuck on:

```
UIView *backgroundColorView = [[UIView alloc] init];
backgroundColorView.backgroundColor = SWITCH_COLOR_ON;
backgroundColorView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
// backgroundColorView.layer.borderWidth = 10.0f; // this shrinks the entire view
[cell setSelectedBackgroundView:backgroundColorView];
```

Any tips on how to make this work? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the easiest solution is to add 2 layers to the view like this:

```
CALayer *leftBorder = [CALayer layer];
[leftBorder setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];
[leftBorder setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 5, yourView.frame.size.height)];
[yourView.layer addSublayer:leftBorder];

CALayer *rightBorder = [CALayer layer];
[rightBorder setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]];
[rightBorder setFrame:CGRectMake(yourView.frame.size.width-5, 0, 5, yourView.frame.size.height)];
[yourView.layer addSublayer:rightBorder];
```

This code add two black borders of 5 pixels width and black color. Hope it helps.

Comment: Worked well, thanks! The only thing I'd mention is that it has to be *(0,0,10,height) and (width-10,0,10,height). Thanks anyways! Cheers